# How to uniquely obfuscate Strings?

Tags: java

I have a huge list of strings that have an arbitrary length. I know want to obfuscate the strings in a way that guarantees certain criteria:

- The obfuscated strings have to be unique
- There should be no easy way to undo the obfuscation

Is there any framework that does this for me?

Comment: This sounds to pretty clearly require actual encryption.

Comment: Here's an interesting article i found while browsing Java obfuscation techniques :https://web.archive.org/web/20161217190546/http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want hashing. The Google Guava [Hashing](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained) API provides some good implementations which will do what you are looking for. You will want to choose one with no collisions.

Comment: There is no such thing as hashing without collisions. Collisions are part of the essence of hash functions.

Comment: Ok, let's say very unlikely in a constrained data space. :-)

Comment: Yes, cryptographically strong hashes will be collision-free for all practical purposes. But I also doubt that OP doesn't need a reversible transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to obfuscate strings in your program so that they don't just show up with a strings or hex tool when your executable is examined, this open source tool can be useful, you don't necessarily have to even encrypt and decrypt these strings during runtime.

Instead, you can combine, any of the following methods:

1. Storing each character as a numeric expression (i.e. instead of 'C' assign 60+7);
2. Add "garbage data" (i.e. after the null character, assign more values afterward, of course using a large enough string to hold the extra characters;
3. Finally, place the assignments in random order (i.e. assign char 3, then 1, then 2, etc.).

Please see an example in this [Github](https://github.com/haephrati/TinyObfuscate) repo.